# how to set datepicker when clicked on both textbox and calendar button?

Tags: jquery

hi i have two text boxes and two calendar buttons beside them,,when you press on calendar button then it popup a calendar then the selected date will come into text box but now my requirement is even when press in text box also the calander popup should come and as well as it also should come when clicked on calendar button.
here my code goes...please cdan any one help me how to modify my code to achieve my requirement as i said.....

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" ,
 showOn: "button",
 buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
 buttonImageOnly: true
 });
 });
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" ,
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true
});
});
  </script>
<body>
<tr>
<td>Memo Start Date :</td>
<td><form:input name="dateOfBirth" id="datepicker1" path="memoStartDate" /> 
    </td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Memo End Date :</td>
<td><form:input id="datepicker2"  path="memoEndDate" /> </td>
    </tr>           
       <tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [showOn: "both"](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn) option to set it

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showOn: "both"
    });
});
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showOn: "both"
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ztcNp/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do showOn: "button" to showOn: "both"
then calendar open on click on button and textbox both.

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showOn: "both"
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: c'mon be real, not going to get anything out of it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
 $(function()     {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();    
 });    
 $(function()     {    
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({    
    changeMonth: true,    
    changeYear: true    
 });           

</script>   
<input  type="text" name="date"  id="datepicker"   />
<input type="text" name="edate"  id="datepicker1"/>
```

Comment: <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });

 $(function() {
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true
});
});

</script>

Comment: this is working i have used in calculating days between two date

Comment: But what if i want to apply different properties for datepicker

Comment: ya only thing needed to discard from OP's question is buttonImageOnly: true,